# Edge - Cant center text horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I try to center a text in a container horizontally and vertically. I tried it by using this css class:

```
.centerVH{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;
}
```

It works fine in chrome and firefox, but it does not work at all in edge browser.

```css
 @media all{
   
    html {
         font-size: 62.5%;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         font-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
     #header_cart {
         width: 180px;
    }

    .uppercase{
      text-transform:"uppercase";
    }
    .centerVH{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      text-align:center;
    }

    .minicart-wrapper .action.showcart{
      display:contents;
    }
   
     #header_cart{
        font-size:1rem;
        -webkit-display:grid;
        -moz-display:grid;
        -ms-display:grid;
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:0% 1fr;
        float:unset;
    }
     #header_cart i{
        color:#39464f;
    }
    
     #mini-wk{
        border:1px solid #f37b22;
        color:#f37b22;
        margin-top:2.5px;
        height:42px;
        background:white;
        position:relative;
    }
    
     .minicart-wrapper:before,.minicart-wrapper:after{
        content:'';
        display:table;
    }

     #minicart_row{
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:70% 1fr;
        grid-template-rows:1fr;
        grid-column-gap:0px;
        grid-row-gap:0px;
    }
     #minicart_row #minicart_col_a{
        grid-area:1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
    }
     #minicart_row #minicart_col_b{
        grid-area:1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
    }
     #minicart_cart_text{
        font-family:"Montserrat";
        font-weight:600;
        font-size:13px;
        color:#ff7712!important;
        text-transform:uppercase;
    }
     #minicart_quote_circle{
        color:#ff7712!important;
    }
     #minicart_quote_count{
        transform:scale(0.75);
    }
     #minicart_quote_count_number{
        font-family:"Montserrat";
        font-weight:600;
        color:white !important;
        font-size:18px;
    }
}

/*! CSS Used from: https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css ;
 media=all */
 @media all{
     .fas{
        display:inline-block;
        font-style:normal;
        font-variant:normal;
        text-rendering:auto;
        line-height:1;
    }
     .fa-2x{
        font-size:2em;
    }
     .fa-stack{
        display:inline-block;
        height:2em;
        line-height:2em;
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:2.5em;
    }
     .fa-stack-1x,.fa-stack-2x{
        left:0;
        position:absolute;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
    }
     .fa-stack-1x{
        line-height:inherit;
    }
     .fa-stack-2x{
        font-size:2em;
    }
     .fa-circle:before{
        content:"\f111";
    }
     .fas{
        font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
    }
     .fas{
        font-weight:900;
    }
}
/*! CSS Used fontfaces */

 @font-face{
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:600;
    font-display:swap;
    src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_bZF3gTD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range:U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
 @font-face{
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:600;
    font-display:swap;
    src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_bZF3g3D_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range:U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
 @font-face{
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:600;
    font-display:swap;
    src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_bZF3gbD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range:U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+0168-0169, U+01A0-01A1, U+01AF-01B0, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
 @font-face{
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:600;
    font-display:swap;
    src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_bZF3gfD_u50.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range:U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
 @font-face{
    font-family:'Montserrat';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:600;
    font-display:swap;
    src:url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v15/JTURjIg1_i6t8kCHKm45_bZF3gnD_g.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range:U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

 @font-face{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    font-display:block;
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot);
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2) format("woff2"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff) format("woff"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf) format("truetype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome) format("svg");
}
 @font-face{
    font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:900;
    font-display:block;
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot);
    src:url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2) format("woff2"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff) format("woff"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf) format("truetype"),url(https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome) format("svg");
}
```

```html
<div id="header_cart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <div id="mini-wk">
        <div id="minicart_row">

            <div id="minicart_col_a" class="action showcart icon">
                <span id="minicart_cart_text" class="centerVH uppercase"> Warenkorb</span>
            </div>

            <div id="minicart_col_b" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <span id="minicart_quote_count" class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                  <i id="minicart_quote_circle" class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                  <i id="minicart_quote_count_number" class="fas fa-stack-1x" data-bind="html: getCartParam('summary_count')">0</i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to figure out how to make it work in Edge. Is there a workaround?

**Expected:**

[image]

**Edge:**

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grwjpo39/3/)

I am using Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 and Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363.

Comment: It is working in my system edge browser Version 87(64-bit)

Comment: Oh ok, so It looks like i have a very old version of edge? So I think it was just not supported back then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm happy to inform you, it works fine on the latest version of Edge.
Maybe you just have an older version?
Or maybe you just need to clear your cache, press this combination for quick clearing of cache `ctrl + shift + delete`.

[image: It works fine on my Edge]

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working in edge. If it for some reason doesn't work for you, why don't you use:

```
position: absolute; /*Or you can use fixed*/
top: 50%;
left: 35%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Here it is in js fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/hgw6uv8k/1/
I tried it in many devices. It works the same for all of them.
[image]

Comment: I tried it and I get a weird result: https://jsfiddle.net/q5sfrgtL/

Comment: Why do we need `transform: translate`? Why not just `position: absolute;` + `top: 30%;` + `left: 10%;` or better yet just `transform: translate(10%, 30%);`?

Comment: Did it work is a bigger question. I too don't understand css very properly. I am just a teen. Also, if you want it to stay in a place similar to the expected version, try tweaking with the numbers!

Comment: It should be auto calculated without any tweaks needed, like in the flex box solution.

Comment: Alright then, I have edited it. It displays it like it has in the expectations.